# Is it possible to deploy HTTP handlers from different verticles in Vert.x

Tags: java, routes, vert.x

From a book "A gentle guide to asynchronous programming with Eclipse Vert.x for Java developers" [I know](http://vertx.io/docs/guide-for-java-devs/#_refactoring_into_independent_and_reusable_verticles) how to deploy HTTP handler in Vert.x from a single verticle:

```
HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
Router router = Router.router(vertx);

router.get("/").handler(this::getRoot);
router.post("/").handler(this::postRoot);

server
  .requestHandler(router::accept)
  .listen(portNumber, ar -> { ... });
```

This is all great but later I need to define `getRoot` and `postRoot` methods in the same class (of course I can use a different class here) and "register" these functions into a router in a *single*, main "HTTP orchestration verticle". Those functions can use event bus and call other verticles, but the registration phase seems to be a bottleneck here: what if I need to handle dozens / hundreds / thousands of URLs? This apprioach won't scale.

Is there a way to split HTTP router configuration between multiple verticles in Vert.x so I can just implement my logic in separate classes without the need to register it somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't split router config over different verticles.

If you have lots of handlers, use [Sub-Routers](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_sub_routers)